# Why pressing Ctrl-h in xterm + tmux sends "^?"?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, gnome-terminal, xterm

`xterm`:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 52; columns 91; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

`gnome-terminal`:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 57; columns 100; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel
iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

When outside `tmux`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> outputs `^H`. Inside `tmux`, I start getting `^?` if run from `xterm`. Inside `screen` run from `xterm` it still outputs `^H`. What's the reason behind this? Should it output `^H` or `^?`? How to remedy this?

Comment: Just to clarify, `^H` is backspace (0x08) and `^?` is `DEL` (0x7f).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that in your xterm, `^H` is the `erase` character, and `tmux` apparently translates the `erase` character to the corresponding control character (`^?`) for the terminal it emulates, so that erasing works as expected in [cooked mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode) (for instance, what happens when you just type `cat`). The translation is needed in case you use a terminal with `^?` as the erase character (generated by the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key), then resume the session with a terminal that uses `^H` as the erase character (generated by the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key). Unfortunately this has visible side effects in some cases, e.g. if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

The only good remedy is to make sure that all your terminals (real or in tmux) use the same `erase` character, which should be `^?` (this is standard nowadays). It seems that your xterm is badly configured. This is not the default configuration, AFAIK.

In any case, you need to make sure to use a `TERM` value for which `kbs=\177`. However this is **not** the case for `xterm-256color` from the official ncurses. So, you either need to select a different `TERM` value or you need to fix the `kbs` entry for `xterm-256color` (this can be done by the end user with: `infocmp > file`, modify `file`, then `tic file`). Some Linux distributions do not have this problem; for instance, Debian has fixed this problem via a `debian/xterm.ti` file in its `ncurses` source package, giving:

```
$ infocmp xterm-256color | grep kbs
        kbs=\177, kcbt=\E[Z, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC,
```

You should also have:

```
$ appres XTerm | grep backarrowKeyIsErase:
*backarrowKeyIsErase:   true
```

Note that you can do `stty erase '^?'` in xterm (before doing anything else), but this is just a workaround (and it may break the behavior of the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key). You should actually have `erase = ^?` (as shown by `stty -a`) by default!

In case problems with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and/or <kbd>Delete</kbd> remain, I recommend the [Consistent BackSpace and Delete Configuration](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html) document by Anne Baretta.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "so that erasing works as expected in cooked mode" part? Who and in which turn processes inputted keys? `This is not the default configuration, AFAIK.` I don't seem to configure it this way, and it's [`arch linux`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/The_Arch_Way), so it's unlikely coming from distribution...

Comment: `you need to make sure to use a TERM value for which kbs=\177; this is true for xterm-256color:` And now that is false, but [it](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm) is [as](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-new) it [should](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-basic) [be](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_kbs), isn't it? Or your `terminfo` database might be
 not so fresh. So, "misconfiguration" must be coming from `terminfo` database in the end.

Comment: A relevant [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/27495725/).

Comment: @x-yuri Hmm... Indeed the official ncurses still has `^H` for xterm-256color, and Debian has a fix (difficult to see since this is not via a patch). I've edited my answer to correct that and say what can be done in your case. I've also added an example for the cooked mode.

Comment: Actually, the part about "cooked mode" became even more fuzzy. It's still not clear from your explanation why `tmux` has to translate `^H` to `^?`. But that must be because `tmux` emulates `screen`, which has `erase = ^?` in `tmux` (but [not in `terminfo`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen) again). I expected you to elaborate on how inputted keys are processed. Say, I press `Ctrl-h`. Then the pressed key is processed by `xterm`. Then, by `tmux`, which translates it. Or when `tmux` is running, `xterm` doesn't do any processing?

Comment: ...`so that erasing works as expected in cooked mode (for instance, what happens when you just type cat).` Are you talking about running `cat`? Or typing a word "cat"? Then it might be any word, I suppose. As far as I understand, when in cooked mode programs gets the whole line, not separate characters. With `erase` characters in it being preprocessed. So, when I press `Ctrl-h`, `tmux` translates it to `^?` so that the other part of `tmux` that emulates `screen` would delete a character before the cursor. Or that's what it looks like to me now.

Comment: ...`The translation is needed in case you use a terminal with ^? as the erase character, then resume the session with a terminal that uses ^H as the erase character.` Do you mean in case I run `tmux` and then detach from it? `Unfortunately this has visible side effects in some cases, e.g. if you type Ctrl+H.` What exactly has side effects? Or which side effects exactly? `Note that you can do stty erase '^?' in xterm... it may break the behavior of the Backspace key).` It won't if I do it in `~/.Xresources`: `xterm*ttyModes: erase ^?`

Comment: ...Speaking of ["Consistent BackSpace..."](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html), my `xterm` by default produces `^[[3~` for `Delete` key. So, `Ctrl-h` -> `^H`, `Backspace` -> `^H`, `Delete` -> `^[[3~`. And what's strange, doing `xterm*ttyModes: erase ^?` without `*backarrowKey: false` doesn't break the behavior of `Backspace` key. Somehow, I don't like the idea of changing `terminfo` database... After all, it reflects `xterm`'s default configuration.

Comment: @x-yuri The `VT100.backarrowKey` user setting is taken into account only if `backarrowKeyIsErase` is false (I don't think this is specific to Debian, but I'm not sure and you can try). So, the xterm(1) man page seems incorrect and I've reported a bug: [Debian bug 775952](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775952). If you set `*ttyModes: erase ^?` with `backarrowKeyIsErase` being true, then the Backspace key should yield `^?`. Setting `backarrowKeyIsErase` to true (default) allows one to ensure that the Backspace key does an erase in cooked mode.

Comment: @x-yuri If tmux forces `erase = ^?` and the terminfo used by tmux has `kbs=^H`, then it is a bug in tmux, which you should report. By `cat`, I mean the `cat` command (with no arguments, and not redirecting stdin). If `erase = ^H` in the real terminal (e.g. your xterm) and `erase = ^?` in the emulated terminal (GNU Screen or tmux), then `^H` should be translated to `^?` to make cooked mode work (GNU Screen is buggy in this respect: run xterm + screen, detach, resume in GNOME Terminal, run `cat`, try the Backspace key); but in raw mode, this translation is visible.

Comment: @x-yuri: Hi - just passing through (while reading with great curiosity), and wanted to mention that the link you mentioned in comment 3 has unfortunately broken. (I have no idea what it points to; also, the Web Archive snapshot redirects to an auth login. >.>)

Comment: I've just started using [Doug Morse's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371687/10454); I haven't tried this one. A question: With this solution, does Control-H still send the DEL key? If so, that's a real problem. Control-H isn't just backspace; it's also, for example, the Help command in emacs. Whatever you use as your erase character, there should be *some* way to send a ^H character from the keyboard.

Comment: @KeithThompson In tmux, Ctrl-h sends the DEL character (`^?`) when in the real terminal (outside tmux), `^H` is the erase character but in tmux, `^?` is the erase character. To avoid that, make sure that the erase character is the same in the real terminal and inside tmux (see `stty -a` output). I suggest that it be `^?` as this is the most common configuration nowadays. This also means that the terminal emulator (Xterm, etc.) needs to be configured so that the Backspace key sends this character.

Comment: @vinc17: So what if I want to send the ^H (ASCII BS) character? I'm not asking how to send an erase character, I'm asking how to send ASCII BS, 0x08.

Comment: @KeithThompson If you want to be able to send the `^H` character (e.g. by typing Ctrl-h), you need to make sure that: if the real terminal has `^H` as the erase character, then the terminal under tmux also has `^H` as the erase character. And more generally, you need to make sure that the erase character outside and inside tmux is the same if you want to be able to send every character; if this is not the case, you'll get an annoying character translation by tmux.

Comment: @vinc17 Outside of tmux, I might have my terminal emulator and tty settings configured to treat DEL as the erase character. I might even set things up so that the Backspace key on my keyboard sends the DEL character (^?, 0x7f). And I might still want to be able to send the Control-H character (ASCII BS, 0x08) from my keyboard -- for example as the Help command in emacs. If I can send every ASCII character *except 0x08*, then that's a problem. Again, I'm not asking about an "erase character". (And Doug Morse's answer solves that for me.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Under Debian/unstable, where DEL is the erase character and the Backspace sends this character, I don't have the issue you're describing with tmux: When I run tmux, then type "cat" (to get the cooked mode), then type Ctrl-H, `^H` is displayed as expected. If this is not your case, there may be a bug somewhere on your machine or some of your configuration is incorrect (maybe an old configuration file).

Comment: @vinc17: Thanks for the information. I'm not sure I'm going to spend time tracking this down, since I have a solution that works for me.

Comment: @KeithThompson Note: I've just noticed that under Debian, xterm has a patch to change `^H` to `\177` for Backspace in some of its termcap/terminfo settings, as it is expected that the Backspace key sends the DEL character. This may have an influence on the applications.

Comment: @vinc17: I have a Debian 9.9.0 VM with xterm version 327-2. Under xterm, Backspace sends ^? and Control-H sends ^H. With my usual X resources setup (`XTerm*backarrowKey: True` and `XTerm*backarrowKeyIsErase: False`), both Backspace and Ctrl-H send ^H (`\x08`). (If Control-H sent anything other than ^H, I'd consider that a bug.) This is all with `TERM=xterm`.

Answer (score 7):

None of the solutions here or elsewhere worked for me.  What did work was adding the following to my `$HOME/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind-key -n Bspace send-keys C-h
```

which makes tmux send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is pressed.

---

I provide some comments, background, and rants below, so feel free to stop reading here. -:)

---

I disagree with vinc17 that the "only good remedy" is to make the backspace / erase character only be ^?.  The user should be able to configure things as he or she see's fit.

A common solution for many of us using Unixes since the days of actual terminals was to use ^H for Backspace and ^? for DEL (i.e., delete after cursor, not before).  The distinction between Ctrl-H and Backspace was and is not always necessary, especially for CLI / terminal programs.

I've been using this mapping of ^H / ^? to Backspace / DEL keys (respectively) since the late '80's, on many machines and both for terminal programs and virtual consoles since the "death" of real terminals, and had no desire to reconfigure my erase character on all my machines and those of my clients (many, many machines) to make Backspace sending ^? work.

I tried all sorts of methods based on all sorts of posts to get tmux to send a Ctrl-H for Backspace.  In particular, "bind-key -n C-h send-keys C-h" not working frustrated me, as I use tmux within Terminator, and I know that my Terminator is set to send Ctrl-H when the Backspace key is pressed.  It took quite a while to stumble upon a post listing the tmux key names available, which is where I found the Bspace keyname, and fortunately that worked to get the ^H character to passthrough tmux correctly (tmux version 2.1-3build1 on Ubuntu 16.04.02).

Comment: the bind-key command in this solution also causes ctrl-h to correctly be sent when typing c-h, and the keyboard backspace to correctly be <del>.

Answer (score 5):

After switching to xterm because of slow-scrolling in xfce4-terminal, I had this same problem. In ~/.Xresources, I set 
`XTerm*ptyInitialErase: true`
. See the xterm man page. This setting leaves the `^H` vs. `^?` to the pseudo-terminal.
To test this, I did Ctrl-V Ctrl-H and indeed this outputs `^H`.

Comment: This was the answer that helped me the most. If you always start xterm in tmux (`xterm -e tmux [...]`), using `stty` in your bashrc won't help; tmux would insert `^?` when Ctrl-H was pressed, due to the tty settings of the terminal where it was started. Running `stty` within tmux does nothing to affect how this works. Xterm needs to START with correct `erase` settings to get tmux to work the same.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to set `XTerm*backarrowKeyIsErase: true` to get backspace working again.